# How to troubleshoot corrupted BytesIO return in django?

Tags: python, django, bytesio

I've got a strange issue going on in django, and am not sure how to even start troubleshooting it.  I am using `xlsxwriter` to generate an Excel report from some data.  I then want to pass the generated file back to the user.  My view code looks like:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
document = gen_excel(today)
filename = 'export_{}.xlsx'.format(today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
response = HttpResponse(
    document.read(),
    content_type='application/ms-excel'
)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename

return response
```

and the function `gen_excel` looks like:

```
def gen_excel(start_date):
    output = io.BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})

    create_sheets(start_date, workbook) # Creates and fills worksheets with data

    workbook.close()
    output.seek(0)

    return output
```

So from `gen_excel`, I am returning the bytesIO stream which was filled by `xlsxwriter`.  My issue is that (using the built-in dev server) the first time I call the view, I get a perfectly readable xlsx file.  All subsequent calls, return a corrupted xlsx file, that can be sort of repaired by excel (though it kills all the formatting, etc..).  If I looks the file sizes, the first output is 40655 bytes, whereas the subsequent downloads are slightly smaller at 40336 bytes.

The kicker is, once I restart the server, the first output is once again perfect.  So it isn't that my `gen_excel` function is changing the data on the server- it seems to be related to subsequent downloads after the server is running.   Also, there are no errors output by django, xlsxwriter, the server, etc.  I just get a corrupt file for all subsequent downloads until the server is restarted.

Any ideas on how I can start troubleshooting this?

Comment: Start debugging by removing the Web from the equation.  If you call the function twice within a simple script, does the problem still happen?

Comment: What if you add this `document.close()` after response formation?

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for that thought.  It turns out that even from the command line, it is getting corrupt, so it must have something to do with my xlsxwriter code.

Comment: I can see two potential issues. The first is that the content_type is wrong and the second is that  HttpResponse should take `document` and not `document.read()` (although it may be able to process either). See the following example from the XlsxWriter docs:  https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_django_simple.html

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara.  Turns out it wasnt either of those issues (I've tried just about every combo of `document`, `document.read()`, `document.value()`, etc.. as well as content types.  I had created a class to handle my formats (as I have a bunch of different formats) and it was acting like a singleton, so on subsequent runs, it was causing issues when the formats were added to the document.